# Insert into random id when detect multi user logged in by ip

Tags: php, mysql

The example I have 3 tables.

Table 1: User

```
 |UserID|IPAddr|
 ——————————————
 |1    | 1234 |
 |2    | 1234 |
 |3    | 1234 |
 |4    | 1234 |
 |5    | 1234 |
 |6    | 1234 |
```

Table 2: Online

```
|UserID|
 ———————
 |1    | 
 |2    | 
 |3    | 
 |4    | 
 |5    | 
 |6    |
```

Table 3: Award

```
|UserID|AwardPoint|
 ——————————————
 |1    | 100      |
 |2    | 100      |
 |3    | 100      |
```

I have a PHP script to check user login by IP Address.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "mydb";
 
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 
$userid = 'UserID';
$table_online = 'Online';
$table_User = 'User';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT UserID as id FROM $table_online");

//ip
$ip_list = $conn->query("select UserID, IPAddr, count(IPAddr) from 
$table_User group by UserID having (count(IPAddr)>3)");
while($row = $ip_list->fetch_assoc())
{
  $ip = $row['IPAddr'];
    
}
//get id
$id_clone = $conn->query("select UserID from $table_User where IPAddr=$ip");
while($row = $id_clone->fetch_assoc())
{
  $id = $row['UserID'];
  echo $id; 
}
// i don't know to do next....
//................. It should insert value 100 to Award table for first 3 
//users or random 3 users on multi users detected!
   
  echo 'success';
} else {
    echo "ERROR! " . $conn->error;
}
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

First, it will select UserID from Online table to get UserID.

Next, It will select IP Address from Table User by UserID which got from table Online.

Then, when it got IPAddress from table User. It will count how many UserID are same IP Address on table User and count UserID list.
If a result is bigger than 3.(It mean by same IP address there are more than 3 users logged in)

I want to insert the value into table Award for only first 3 users(or random 3 users on plus 6 users) on User table if there are more than 3 users logged in.

How can I do it with PHP or SQL query?

I have created check User online, fetch row result from UserID and count it successfully. But I don't know how to Insert Value to table Award for first 3 online users(or random user on the list of users and will stop when inserting to 3 users fully).

Thank you in advance

Comment: For proper answer you should post question in detail with code and we can analyze the code and instruct you what to do next,

Comment: thank you, i will update my post

Comment: what the expected output with this example data?

Comment: will Award table should have unique User or UserID?

Comment: Award table will have unique UserID. Updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this in MySQL alone.

First get the "top 3" users of any online IP addresses, and store that in a temporary table:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp` AS
SELECT `IPAddr`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`UserID`), ',', 3) `Top3`
FROM `Online`
JOIN `User` USING (`UserID`)
GROUP BY `IPAddr`
HAVING LENGTH(`Top3`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`Top3`, ',', '')) = 2;
```

Then use the values from that to add rows to the Award table:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Award` (`UserID`, `AwardPoint`)
SELECT `UserID`, 100
FROM `User`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`UserID`, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Top3`)
  FROM `tmp`
));
```

In theory you could do this in one query, except for the fact that the `User` table is used in both, and you can't open the same table twice when doing things like this.

The way this works is that `GROUP_CONCAT()` will return a comma-separated list of values based on the grouping (in this case, `IPAddr`). This would give you `'1,2,3,4,5,6'`. Then `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is used to get just the first three such values. Since the grouping is by `IPAddr`, if you had two IPs of online users then you'd get multiple rows. `HAVING` is then used to ensure that there are exactly two commas in the result, indicating that there are indeed three users in the result, no fewer.

As for the `INSERT`, the subquery combines all of the rows from the temporary table into one long list of user IDs that were found, without regard for the `IPAddr`. It then looks up users having an ID that is in that set, and awards them 100 points.

What a mess :D Honestly it's probably better to do this kind of processing in PHP but I thought it'd be fun to take a shot at this in MySQL only.

Finally, if `Award` actually has a `` UNIQUE KEY (`UserID`) `` then you can simply add this to the end:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `AwardPoint` = `AwardPoint`+VALUES(`AwardPoint`)
```

This will increment the existing point value if there is one.

Comment: I will try to add your answer to my script and report later. Thank you

Comment: Absolutely my problem is solved . Thank you bro. You are god!